# my 'for loop' is giving errors. eventhough syntax seems correct

Tags: pine-script

I am experiencing some problems with a small chunk of code.

I am trying to count bars closing  above/below the ema. with the following code:

```
int barsAboveMA = 0 
int barsBelowMA = 0

for i = 1 to 5 
     if close[i] < ema[i]
          barsBelowMA += 1
     if close[i] > ema[i]
          barsAboveMA += 1
```

but keep getting the same error:

```
Incorrect 'for' statement. Expecting 'to <expression>'
```

I've tried adding a 'by 1' but then I get the error:

```
'if' cannot be used as a variable or function name.
```

Answer (score 0):

In a if or for block, the new lines must start with 4 spaces or 1 tab. Yours start with 5 spaces.

```
for i = 1 to 5 
    if close[i] < ema[i]
        barsBelowMA += 1
    if close[i] > ema[i]
        barsAboveMA += 1
```

Comment: thank you. but im still getting the same error

Comment: Please count the sapces after you copy the code I shared.

Comment: ive tried both 4 and 5 spaces. also tried deleting the indent and then tabbing it no luck ;(

Comment: Share your complete code please.

Comment: where can i share it ^^ sorry very new to coding and stackoverflow

Comment: Just edit your question and add it there please.

Comment: code is too long. but i apreciate your efforts!

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can try this instead, this is just an example:

```
//this is C# code:
int barsAboveMA = 0; //both variables
int barsBelowMA = 0;

//a for loop structure that it will loop 5 times:
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    if (close[i] < ema[i])
    {
        barsBelowMA++;
    }
    if (close[i] > ema[i])
    {
        barsAboveMA++;
    }
}
```

It is a C# code but the structure is pretty general, so I hope that you can use it in any languaje!
Hope that helps you!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).